How should I adapt my software's keyboard shortcuts for macOS users (e.g. when to use Cmd instead of Ctrl)?
I'm not familiar with macOS at all. Nevertheless, when designing cross-platform software features, one needs to be aware of such small differences. I've seen a lot of keybindings which are usually Ctrl+ (something) on Windows and Linux and Cmd+(something) on Mac.
For some standard actions (e.g. copy, save, etc.) you can easily find information on what the expected shortcut should be. However, when it's a software-specific action that's not so simple, especially if your software is some sort of plugin or component of a larger third-party program.
One can easily assume that Ctrl is equivalent to Cmd works as a general guideline, but does it really?
General question
When does this apply? When can I simply assume macKey = otherOsKey.replace('Ctrl+', 'Cmd+')?
For what keys or combinations? Or for what kind of actions?
I'm asking more in terms of good practice guidelines rather than an exhaustive list.
What I read about it makes it seem like ⌘ (Cmd) is similar to the WinKey, which I would think of as an OS-defined action that I'd probably want to avoid clashing with. E.g. maybe it makes sense for cross-app standard stuff like copy, save, etc. but not for some very specific action in my software?
Specific question
I want this particular feature to be on Ctrl+F1 on Windows and Linux.
Can I just use Cmd+F1 or should I expect it to clash with OS keybindings or a different expected behavior (because it's F1-F12 instead of a letter)? Should I use something else for specific actions of my app? This particular action would be a sort of "open documentation" action; but I'd like to also know what I should do in general.

I think in most cases app shortcuts, especially those still active when a textarea/field is focused, should always be prefixed with cmd, optionally with shift and/or ctrl. Ctrl and option shortcuts in macOS textareas are mostly used for text editing and cursor movements. This is especially true when the user has a custom DefaultKeyBinding.dict. You should not override them.

The best guide is Apple's Interface Guidelines - for keys see https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/keyboards

I find cmnd and ctrl do different things: cmnd+shift +; is a shortcut for time, while changing to control gives the date...

I would avoid the F-Keys, because many users have them set to be used as 'system' keys, for volume, brightness etc & may not immediately realise that they will have to use Fn/Cmd/F-key to invoke the 'true' F-key.

Thanks! This is on VSCode btw. I believe I'll end up using ⌥⌘D. I also considered alternatives like ⇧⌘/ (i.e. ? as in "help") but it seems to clash and ⌥⇧⌘/ seems too complicated. On Windows/Linux F1 is often used for "help"-related commands, so I'd rather use ⌥F1 if possible, assuming macOS had this convention too (does it?), but if it can be a bad idea, maybe not.
